# Remove attribute from component tag in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Learning Angular components here. Their tutorial has the following example of "injecting" the custom tag for a component into html:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  <b>Hero</b><br>
  <hero-detail hero="ctrl.hero"></hero-detail>
</div>
```

I, however, want to achieve what I've seen many people do: remove the hero="ctrl.hero" part and end up having just:

```
<hero-detail></hero-detail>
```

How do I remove all the "extras"? I was trying to find some tutorials but it all end up being the same as above... :( Suggestions?

Comment: if the attributes are unneeded, just don't include them. `angular.module('example').directive('hero-detail', () => { template: 'I Am A Hero' })`

Comment: So, question here. That tutorial (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) doesn't even work with directives. I've never used one in my life. Should I write on to do that?